# Boxplot Chart not displaying on deployment (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, boxplot

I just added a new plugin to my project to display boxplot charts on Angular 7 using chart.js: https://github.com/datavisyn/chartjs-chart-box-and-violin-plot.

Working in local I had no problem to work with this new chart type. I used this example as a model to implement the chart in my project: https://github.com/sluger/ng-chartjs-boxplot. The versions of the libraries that I use are the exact same. This example is provided in the documentation of the plugin.

When I deploy my app, the chart does not display and I get this error:
`Uncaught Error: "boxplot" is not a chart type.` as if the plugin is not implemented.
Again, this does not happen on local.

I did not found any related issues.

I did not found either other plugins that I can use for replacement to display boxplot charts.

Thanks

Here is the component ts code that reproduce the error:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

function randomValues(count, min, max) {
  const delta = max - min;
  return Array.from({ length: count }).map(() => Math.random() * delta + min);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = {
    // define label tree
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Dataset 1",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)",
        borderColor: "red",
        borderWidth: 1,
        outlierColor: "#999999",
        padding: 10,
        itemRadius: 0,
        data: [
          randomValues(100, 0, 100),
          randomValues(100, 0, 20),
          randomValues(100, 20, 70),
          randomValues(100, 60, 100),
          randomValues(40, 50, 100),
          randomValues(100, 60, 120),
          randomValues(100, 80, 100)
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "Dataset 2",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)",
        borderColor: "blue",
        borderWidth: 1,
        outlierColor: "#999999",
        padding: 10,
        itemRadius: 0,
        data: [
          randomValues(100, 60, 100),
          randomValues(100, 0, 100),
          randomValues(100, 0, 20),
          randomValues(100, 20, 70),
          randomValues(40, 60, 120),
          randomValues(100, 20, 100),
          randomValues(100, 80, 100)
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  options = {
    legend: {
      position: "top"
    }
  };
}
```

Here is the HTML:
`<chart type="boxplot" [data]="data" [options]="options"></chart>`

Here is the app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ChartModule } from "angular2-chartjs";
import "chartjs-chart-box-and-violin-plot/build/Chart.BoxPlot.js";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ChartModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```